# Angular Material - including checkbox

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to include checkbox in my page provided by angular material but failing to do so
You can find the plunkr [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/8JwSAFyTu7LiE3e5OUL2?p=preview).

```
<md-content>
            <md-list-item class="md-2-line" ng-repeat="questions in questionsList">
              <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
                <h3>{{questions.question}}</h3>

                <md-checkbox class="md-secondary" ng-repeat="option in questions.options">{{option}}</md-checkbox>

              </div>
              </md-list-item>
          </md-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'ngMaterial' you need to inject ng-material in app.js

like this

```
var app = angular.module('App', ['ngMaterial'])
```

Comment: I feel like puking on myself.